# How to pass downloading file details into async callback method and showing the progressbar like x files out of y has been downloaded

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am building a WP7 app in which I am having a list of objects. Object have properties like URL, filename. So the problem is how can I pass the current object to async callback method so that after download i can save it with filename. I don't want to take global variable for filename.

Secondly I want to show progress-bar with text 1 0f 5 downloaded. How exactly can I achieve this.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create helper DTO class that will store all information you need.
For example,

```
 internal class TrackDownloadState
 {
    public string Filename;
    public string Id;
    public Uri Source;
    // and so on, all the information you need
 }
```

If you use Webclient, use parameter token in methods DownloadStringAsync or OpenReadAsync 
Details on these methods: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144203(v=vs.95).aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144212(v=vs.95)

If you use HttpWebRequest, then use parameter state in method BeginGetResponse.
Details on that method: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Thanks @Alex Sorokoletov for the help . I was already using the FilesToBeDownloaded class for the all files but passing usertoken in OpenReadAsync solved my problem. Thanks alot.

Comment: Hi @Alex Sorokoletov can u suggest how to achieve the second part in WP7

Comment: Showing progressbar with text? Use Grid with 2 RowDefinitions, in 1st put the textblock, in 2nd put progressbar itself.  When you completed dowload, update these controls on UI thread (use System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke method to run code on UI)